# Constructor/Destructor call order on stack

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, assignment-operator

I have the following simple code:

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) { cout << "Constructor a=" << a << endl; }
    ~A()            { cout << "Destructor  a=" << a << endl; }
    void print()    { cout << "Print       a=" << a << endl; }
};

void f()
{
    A a(1);
    a.print();
    a = A(2);
    a.print();
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Constructor a=1
Print       a=1
Constructor a=2
Destructor  a=2
Print       a=2
Destructor  a=2
```

I find that there are two destructor calls with `a=2` and none with `a=1` while there is one constructor call for each case. So how are contructors and destructros called in this case?

Comment: Why would you expect a destructor call with `a=1`?

Comment: Did you spot the temporary `A` value? It doesn't live very long.

Comment: I spotted it now Kerrek. Wow the answers are pouring in. I see clearly know. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're not destroying `A(1)` you're assigning `A(2)` to it, let's extend your example by adding [assign operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C++%29):

```cpp
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) { cout << "Constructor a=" << a << endl; }
    ~A()            { cout << "Destructor  a=" << a << endl; }
    void print()    { cout << "Print       a=" << a << endl; }
    A &operator=(const A &other) {
        cout << "Assign operator old=" << a << " a=" << other.a << endl; 
        a = other.a;
    }
};
```

Which will result to:

```
[vyktor@grepfruit tmp]$ ./a.out 
Constructor a=1
Print       a=1
Constructor a=2
Assign operator old=1 a=2 <- This line explains why destructor is not called
Destructor  a=2
Print       a=2
Destructor  a=2
```

If you have one of these implemented:

- **Destructor** - Destruct all the object's members
- **Copy constructor** - Construct all the object's members from the equivalent members in the copy constructor's parameter
- **Copy assignment operator** - Assign all the object's members from the equivalent members in the assignment operator's parameter

you should implement all of them. This is called [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Answer (score 7):

```
a = A(2);
```

Will use default `operator=` to assign new value to `a`, setting it's `a::a` member value to 2.

```
void f()
{
    A a(1);//a created with int constructor a.a == 1
    a.print();// print with a.a == 1
    a = A(2);//Another A created with int constructor setting a.a == 2 and immediately assigning that object to a
    //object created with A(2) deleted printing 2 it was created with
    a.print();//a.a==2 after assign
}//a deleted printing 2 it was assigned with
```

You probably should read about [Rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to get better understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

```
void f()
{
    A a(1);
      //  Constructor a=1
    a.print();
      //  Print       a=1
    a = A(2);
      // Constructor a=2
      // also operator=
      // Destructor  a=2
    a.print();
      // Print       a=2
      // Destructor  a=2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void f()
{
    A a(1); // Constructor a=1 (a.a(1) is called)
    a.print(); // Print a=1
    a = A(2); // Constructor a=2 (Temporary unnamed object A(2) is constructed)
              // compiler generated a.operator=(const A&); is called and then
              // Destructor  a=2 (Temporary unnamed object is destroyed.
    a.print(); // Print a=2
              // Destructor  a=2 (a.~a() is called)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First the constructor for a=1 is called

Second the print is called

Third the new object which you created A(2) has its constructor called.

Fourth this object is assigned to object a so data member of object a=2

Fifth the destructor for object A(2) is called

Sixth the destructor for object a is called